# Flutter apk/ipa size vs React Native apk/ipa size

Tags: react-native, flutter

React Native APK size for a hello world example is around 20M ([in recent versions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23575)) because of support different hardware architectures (ARMv7, ARMv8, X86, etc) while Flutter APK size for same application is around 7M.

What's the reason for the difference in size? Do Flutter support all hardware architecture?

Comment: what do you mean by `"hardware architecture"`?

Comment: @pskink I think ARMv7, ARMv8 , X86 .etc he wanted to mention.

Comment: @pskink yes, I mean something like ARMv7...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Junius answer is correct but I don't believe covers the reason why. So Flutter compiles to **100% native code**, where RN uses a combination of native code and JavaScript communicating across a bridge.

That is why Flutter does not need to add the `JavaScript core` thus, the size is smaller. But anyway, as your app grows, the JS part will always be around the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Visit to below mentioned url's and may be they could help you out regarding what you are looking for.

https://nevercode.io/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-a-developers-perspective/

https://android.jlelse.eu/comparing-apk-sizes-a0eb37bb36f

if not it will still give more insights to others on how Flutter is different than others, and whether one should choose flutter over any other hybrid app development technology or not.

Answer (score 2):

RN use open source `JavaScriptCore`, which is the default engine for Safari. RN iOS and Android apps don't have the same size. For iOS RN uses the JavaScriptCore provided by the iOS platform, and for Android RN bundles `JavaScriptCore` with the app, which increases the size of the app. The reason why Flutter and RN Hello World differ in size is because of `JavaScriptCore`.

Comment: My question is not about why the exported version size is different in iOS and Android.

Comment: That's what I said here *The reason why Flutter and RN Hello World differ in size is because of JavaScriptCore*

Comment: *for Android RN bundles JavaScriptCore with the app, which increases the size of the app*

Answer (score 2):

The day before yesterday I published an Flutter application in which there are also images. However, the application has libraries that are not small like Firebase and I managed to make it become 2.3 Mb. Instead, I have another Flutter app that I published and weighs 8.5 Mb, do you want to know the only difference? The Api Min starts from 21, while the one that weighs 8.5 from 16. This is a big advantage because 2.3 are very few. Only in debug mode the size is very large, so don't worry, because when you compress the flutter application in appBundle for example to the Play Store, the size of him smallest very more.

[image]